# Does Serenity have a ship prefix?

Tags: firefly

In *Firefly*, Allied ships have the prefix IAV, but is there a similar prefix (like MV or SS) for merchant space ships like Serenity?

Comment: In the real world, naval vessels have prefixes like USS and HMS while private ships do not.

Comment: I beieve that British steam ships have the prefix SS and British oil powered ships have the prefix MV for Motor Vessel.

Answer (score 9):

**Looking at the ships documents,** there is no prefix for ships like Serenity that are licensed for cargo.

[image: Serenity Ship's Documents]
*Image of documents reproduced from Firefly: A Celebration (Titan Books, ISBN 9781781161685)*

According to Commander Harken, however, there are *"No mandatory registration markings on the bow."* (Firefly: Bushwacked) which implies something other than just the name of the ship is required to be displayed and I woud have expected that to be on ship's documents as well as the bow if required by law.

We do get a look at another ship called the Brutus in the pilot episode. Formerly a liner but now in the passenger and cargo business, this ship does not seem to display registration markings either.
[image: Brutus]

The only other number I can find seems to be the equivalent of a car's VIN or chassis number, **03-K64-FF**, which does not resemble a pre-fix.

[image: Serenity's ship number]

Comment: Could you explain where these documents are from?

Comment: Thanks @Valorum - answer edited with source reference added.